# UILabel have to access keyboard alphabets only

Tags: iphone, xcode

can anyone tell how to access only alphabets through keyboard. Numbers and special characters should not de entered into the `UILabel`.

I'am new to iOS programming and I'am searching this from last 2 hours of no use. Help me out of this

Comment: are you using textField?

Answer (score 0):

try this ...

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range 
{
     static NSCharacterSet *charSet2 = nil;
   if(textField==txtfirstname)
  {
    if(!charSet2)
    {

    charSet2 = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ "] invertedSet];

    } 
        NSRange location = [string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:charSet2];
        return (location.location == NSNotFound);
  }
}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: @user1986984 : change - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range  to - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string

Answer (score 0):

To get a notification you'll have to use the delegate function of UITextField. If you use the UILabel. You might have to go ahead and use the Keyboard notifications. Instead what you can do is use the UITextField. You can use the UITextField border style property to make it look a like UILabel.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
    { 
        NSCharacterSet *myCharSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"];
        for (int i = 0; i < [string length]; i++) 
        {
            unichar c = [string characterAtIndex:i];
            if (![myCharSet characterIsMember:c]) 
            {
                return YES;
            }
            else 
            {
                return NO;
            }
         }
    }
```